# Want to use c++ or perl to send a file over the internet using OpenSSH and SFTP---Windows Vista both

Tags: sftp, openssh

I Want to use c++ or perl to send a file over the internet using OpenSSH and SFTP.
Both Computers will be running Windows Vista. The C++  would be a Console Program.

How do I accomplish this?

Thank You.

I

Answer (score 0):

For a Perl solution check [Net::SFTP::Foreign](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aSFTP%3a%3aForeign).

Though on Windows, nowadays, the [Net::SSH2](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aSSH2) backend ([Net::SFTP::Foreign::Backend::Net_SSH2](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aSFTP%3a%3aForeign%3a%3aBackend%3a%3aNet_SSH2)) is probably a better option than the default OpenSSH one.